# CSS: One DIV each line, stack image and text horizontally within a DIV, and apply margins

Tags: css

I wrote the code below, and it kind of works except that margins are not working. See the image below. I want margins between `item`s and between the image and the text. How can I get the layout I want? I don't have to use `float=left` if there is a better way.

```css
.item {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
}

.leftImage {
  float: left;
}

.rightText {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that in the `item` divs, you have floating elements, so the `item` does have margin on the bottom, but the float is taking it out of the element flow. You need to clear the float on the `item` div. Create a CSS rule `.item::after { content: ''; display: block; clear: both; }` Also, add `float: left` to your `.rightText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer with keeping your floats, using a pseudo element to clear the floating elements in `item`.

```css
.item {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
}

.item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.leftImage {
  float: left;
}

.rightText {
  margin-left: 1em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>
```

Here's the same layout, removing floats, using `display: flex` on your `item`.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.rightText {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>
```

In regards to the top margin on the `.rightText`, the browser is adding that. You can remove that using `margin-top: 0`.

[image: browser dev tools image]

Comment: Thank you. I was writing about the text's left margin not working, but adding float to it as your updated answer, all worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working! You can use either example I provided. Please mark this answer as accepted if it meets your requirements.

Comment: The second one using `flex`, too, and it was simpler, so I will use that instead. I was trying to mark it as the answer, but the system said I have to wait a minute. I'll do it after adding this comment.

Comment: There is one problem. The text is not aligned with the image (to the top of the DIV). There is a margin above the text. I think somehow the item's bottom margin is affecting the text. Can it be fixed?

Comment: You can add `margin-top: 0` to the `rightText`. The browser is automatically adding that margin. If you use the dev tools in your browser, you'll see that the browser styles are adding `margin-top: 16px`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `display:flex;` instead:

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: flex;
}

.rightText {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `clear` in the `.item` div, nor do you need `float` on the `.leftImage` div. If you look at my answer, I have the flex example as well.

Comment: You're true. I just copy-past code as provided. I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix to containers of floating elements is overflow: hidden:

```css
.item {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.leftImage {
  float: left;
}

.rightText {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
  <p class="rightText">Hello <br/> world.</p>
</div>
```